# How to To Write whole .txt file to a Column field through MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**I Want To Write whole .txt file to a Column field through MySQL.**

I have a table called DBInfo with bunch of records, I just inserted a new column called `ExtraInfo`.  Now I have 100's of text files in my local drive.  I just want to write each text file to newly added column.

For Example : for primary key `ID =  "1"` ,  I want to write the file `C:\client\1.text` to the newly added column `ExtraInfo` , similarly for `ID = "2"` I need to write `C:\client\2.text` in respective field,

and so on...

Thanks In advance !

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a site to ask people to write code for you. What have you tried yourself? where did you get stuck?

Comment: i'm not? i just asked you what have you tried so far? did you manage to get all the filenames you want to read? were you able to read them? where did you get stuck?

Comment: You want to put the filenames in `ExtraInfo`, or you want to put the contents of each file into the column?

Comment: I don't think SQL has any way of reading files into each field. You can use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to read one CSV or XML file into a whole table, but there's no way to read a different file into just one column in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to put the filenames into the column, you can do it with a simple `UPDATE` statement that calculates the filename from the ID.

```
UPDATE DBInfo
SET ExtraInfo = CONCAT('C:\\client\\', ID, '.text')
```

If you want to put the contents of each file into the column, there's no way to do that just in SQL. You could do it with a PHP script that reads each file into a variable and then uses the variable in an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Thank you Barmar , Actually, I want to put the contents of each file into the column.   And yes I tried LOAD DATA INFILE , like :

Comment: Thank you Barmar , Actually, I want to put the contents of each file into the column.   And yes I tried LOAD DATA INFILE , like :
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\client\\1.txt' 
INTO TABLE test
This query is putting all contents of file on very first colum i.e. ID, As I want to put the contents on the last column named as "ExtraInfo " ,
Secondly, this query is putting the files contents on more than one fields, for example, if my text file is having 5 rows, then its dumping each of the text file rows to 5 different rows of the first column (ID) of the table.

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` is for loading things like CSV files: each line of the file becomes a row of the table, and each field in the file is a column. It's not for what you're trying to do. You need to use a client programming language to do it.

Comment: Also, `LOAD DATA INFILE always creates new rows, it can't update existing rows.

Comment: You can use optional parameters to `LOAD DATA INFILE` to tell it which column to put the data in.